# What type of range is used when working with whole numbers?

Tags: mysql, range, database-schema

I am trying to create my first DB, I noticed that the ranges are not optional and you must think into the future and select reasonable ranges, I came up with these ranges:

```
*(NUM 0...65199)
(CHAR 1...35)
(CHAR 1...35)
*(NUM 0...999999999)
(BOOLEAN)
*(NUM 1...20)
(BOOLEAN)
*(NUM 1...9)
*(NUM 0...9)
*(NUM 0...9)
*(NUM 1...9)
*(NUM 1...9999)
*(NUM 1...9999)
*(NUM 0...99)
(TIME_STAMP)
(TIME_STAMP)
(BOOLEAN)

*all my NUM are whole numbers, decimals will never exist
```

But I am confussed on what type to use, and how to even specify the accepted values (hope this second one is optional):

(to be edited - can't add image low rep) https://i.stack.imgur.com/WS6yO.png

But mostly, I want to know what type to use when I will not be working with any decimals.

Answer (score 0):

Here check out this table of data types

http://www.w3resource.com/mysql/mysql-data-types.php